# ¿Cómo guardar la semana actual en un modelo de Django?

Tags: python, django

Por ejemplo para guardar la fecha actual es de la siguiente manera:

```
 fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Creo suponer que debe existir una forma para guardar automáticamente la semana actual, intenté hacer esto:

```
    semana= fecha_creacion.isocalendar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Está en la documentación de Python sobre [stftime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

```
fecha_creacion.strftime('%U')
```

- `%U` - devuelve el número de la semana del año en un número del 00 al 53, las semanas empiezan en domingo... excepto en año nuevo, donde todos los días antes del primer domingo son parte de la semana 00.